# Track ingredients from products (breakfast service)

Tags: product, products, bundled-product, stock, extensions

I'm working on a breakfast service website, and the company wants to be able to track the stock of the ingredients, so they know what and when they have to buy new ingredients for their breakfasts. I've already checked the Magento Connect website for extensions and Google for answers, but i don't know where to look elsewhere for help.

I've also tried adding the ingredients manually, and then set the breakfasts up as Bundled Products, but there is another problem: The customers should also be able to customize 2 set breakfasts that contain a set number of ingredients, they should only be able to add ingredients to it and not be able to remove the required ingredients from that product.

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Each breakfast set is one bundle product. A bundle can has required options that cannot be removed:
Use the option type "checkbox", only add one selection and make the option " required "

Answer (score 0):

You can use Related products. In magento standard, you have a list for this.

How it works: To the product you can add a parameter `related_product` which is a comma seperated list to add whatever products you want. So with a little bit of JS you should achieve with a bundle product what you want.

```
\Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction
$product = $this->_initProduct();
$related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
if (!empty($related)) {
    $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
}
```